# Vb.net Trying to close a form opened in a Panel. But on closing it, the Parent from gets close/hide totally

Tags: vb.net

I tried all options on google. But they show only the form.Close or form.Hide for each loop. I also have implemented same loop as follows:-
(I am adding the form into Panel (Panel_Details_Container)

```
    For Each form_obj In Panel_Details_Container.Controls.OfType(Of Form).ToList()
        form_obj.Close()
    Next
    Try
        '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
        '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Dim Form_DE_Details_Obj As New Form_DE_Details()
        '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Form_DE_Details_Obj.ControlBox = False
        Form_DE_Details_Obj.Text = String.Empty
        '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Form_DE_Details_Obj.TopLevel = False
        '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Form_DE_Details_Obj.TextBox_Selected_Unique_ID.Text = Selected_Unique_ID.ToString()
        Form_DE_Details_Obj.TextBox_Selected_Imp_ID.Text = Selected_IMP_ID.ToString()
        '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Form_DE_Details_Obj.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
        Form_DE_Details_Obj.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.WindowsDefaultLocation
        '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
        '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Form_DE_Details_Obj.Visible = True
        Panel_Details_Container.Controls.Add(Form_DE_Details_Obj)
        Form_DE_Details_Obj.Show()
        '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
    '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**My Issue:-**
 1. The .Close worked for all forms which had less controls.
 2. This particular form has lot of controls each 20 rows :-7 ComboBox, 3 TextBox, 3 checkbox, 1 button. So is it any memory issue? That closing and immediately reloading the form instance, parent form gets close automatically?
 3. I confirmed this that the problem is of this form only by passing the other forms worked smoothly and whenever this form is called the parent form gets closed.
 4. In title I wrote close/hide because I am not aware whether the parent form get close or hides. As after Parent form get close/invisible, the wait mouse cursor runs or a process on breakpoint stops at code side. But the parent as well newly created form are not at all available.
(These are few tips I am placing which I tried since now complete week)

**Purpose of code:-**
 1. A lot of controls are saved on one form. And when needed the appropriate 
    form with restricted controls to that module only are loaded.
 2. Due to splitting the controls to other individual forms, lot of memory is reduced.

**My Workouts on resolving the issue already:-**
 1. Tried .Hide already. But this creates reloading a new form object instance every time and new instance for form along with its all objects are in memory. I tested this by giving breakpoint at from_obj.Hide() and everytime a new form instance count gets added in loop.
 2. .Dispose also did not helped out.
 3. I tried Application.DoEvents (to check if it reqires too much time to close form resources). But no resolution.

Thank you very much in advance to you all.

Comment: What you can do to check if this is indeed the problem is to remove the `try-catch` code and move it to a `button`. First close all forms and then add the new form clicking the `button`.

Comment: @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε :Thank you for your prompt answer. I tried the way you suggested. As I mentioned the first instance goes well. But when again the call is made, and the form_obj.Close statement fires, before any further process the parent form gets invisible. But the process runs completely without any error.

Comment: If you use **only** this form and close it normally, without the loop, `.....Close()` do you see the same problem?

Comment: @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε: It is a working code in the form. When I was using it in the current Parent form, it was working without any issues. But then as I mentioned I had 7 different modules which I split into individual forms. With exact same process calling each derived form. Out of which 6 are running smooth with .Close() but this is  only giving unexpected action after .Close()

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue adding a form with 2000 controls but it worked fine. So something else is the issue not the closing of the form. Can you post a minimal code that indeed causes the problem to test it my self?

Comment: @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε:Super! You did half of my job by testing on 2000 controls. That's really sweet of you. I would do one thing, I would inspect once the parent form as well as calling form only once again  thoroughly line by line, to check any conflict with closing of form indirectly. Just give me some time, and I would revert back.

Comment: Look in the Output window for any exception notification, if you see one then there's an unwise Try/Catch somewhere.  Use Dispose() instead of Close().

Comment: Probably not the source of the issue, but the code does not remove the closed `Form` from `Panel_Details_Container.Controls`.

Comment: @HansPassant: Already tried .Dispose but it works exactly as .Close()

Comment: @TnTinMn: Just going one step towards it. I put form_obj.Visible == true. And it flickers after the parent form gets closed and the called form is for few seconds now on screen and vanishes,

Comment: @HansPassant: I tried Add Watch. But it works fine till it gets closed. Once .Close() fires the ParentForm property instant goes null. But through breakpoints as said the new instance & controls are intact but ParentForm goes hidden. And hence newly called form is not visible and not accessible.